# loaded image Qsize

Tags: qt, qt4

how can i get the image size when i load image  (  width, height )

Comment: Size as in number of pixels per dimension, or the number of bytes the image occupies in memory?

Answer (score 2):

QImage has a method called size(). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: thanks,is not the answer i look after. if i open a image how can get the image size

Answer (score 0):

[`QImage::width()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html#width)

[`QImage::height()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html#height)

You really should read the documentation.

Jim's method works as well, just call width and height on the returned size.